# Move my owncloud data directory (running owncloud 9)

Tags: 14.04, permissions, apache2, php, owncloud-server

So I have an 14.04 server that I've installed owncloud9 on. Everything works fine. i can connect with a browser and using my phone like a champ. the problem is...i want to change my data directory. I created a small raid1 that i want to use solely for my cloud space. i created and tested so i know the space is working. i saw a video that said you basically just move the data (in my case, `/var/www/owncloud/data`) to its new spot, direct config.php to its new destination and restart apache2:

`sudo mv /var/www/owncloud/data /cloud_space/cloud_data`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

After doing this i can get to the login screen but it says to check for an `.ocdata` file. files wasn't there. i read that some people were able to just add the file so i tried that and restarted apache. nothing changed. i read that i had to change the permissions so i just opened everything up in the folder for now 777. i went as far as just opening the whole drive to test it when that didn't work but nothing. i haven't seen/read anything else besides this way of doing it. All i want to do is change the data directory. It looked so simple on the video. I've uninstalled and purged owncloud quite a few time trying to get this to work this way and it DOES work up until i start messing with moving it.

**Question:** Is there a different way to do this? or is there something i have to do besides adding the `.ocdata` file to it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you somehow copied the data directory without the hidden files (.xxx files)
Please copy the complete data directory. You also have to make sure that the new data directory has the exact same owner and permissions. This is sometimes tricky on a NAS which might not support all permissions. I also recommend to upgrade to Nextcloud because it comes with better security features. 
If something is still wring with the permissions then check the webserver logfile or the logfile in the data directory.

Comment: I'm actually looking at next cloud right now. I have changed owner and permissions to match several times. Even just went 777 with no changes.  Is there something besides mv that would do a better job moving data?